# file transfer with https.request

Tags: file, https, lua, tls1.2, tls1.3

With the deprecation of TLSV1, file transfer from a host server stopped working.
I am trying to download a file from url = https://dropbox.com/xxxxxxxxxxxdl=1 and save the file on the gateway to a local file using tlsv1_2 or tlsv1_3. From the code below and other example son this topic seems the following should work but I do not understand how sendString should be configured.

```
 --downloadfile - downloads a file to the gateway
-–Returns:
-–result - result of this function
-–filename - name of file
-–fulllocalpath - path where file is stored locally
-–resultstr - status info
local function downloadfile(filename, url, isbinary)
local string1 = " Downloading file from: " … url
–-print(“UMONIoT”,“INFO”, string1)

-- retrieve the content of a URL
local rawname = url
local fname = filename  --rawname:match("[%w+.%w]+$")
local fulllocalpath = FTPATH .. fname

log("UMONIoT","INFO", "Starting download to local directory: " .. fulllocalpath)
local resultstr = "Starting download to local directory: " .. fulllocalpath .."\r" 
--local response, resultcode

local response_body = {}
local response, resultcode, respheaders, respstatus;


if rawname:match("https://") then
    local https = require'ssl.https'
    
    --response, resultcode = https.request(url) --TLZ commented out v1.4.6 5/9/23, replaced with following code to enable file transfer using tlsv1_2
    response, resultcode, respheaders, respstatus  =  https.request{
    --response, resultcode =  https.request{
        url = rawname,
        protocol = 'tlsv1_2',
        method = 'POST',
                headers = {
            [“content-type”] = “application/x-www-form-urlencoded”,
            [“content-length”] = string.len(sendString) --<---What is sendString????
        },
        
        sink = ltn12.sink.table(response_body),
        source = ltn12.sourcee.string(sendString)
    }
    --p(response, resultcode)
    log("UMONIoT","INFO", "File download response [" .. response .. "].")
    log("UMONIoT","INFO", "File download resultcode [" .. resultcode .. "].")
    --log("UMONIoT","INFO", "File download respheaders [" .. respheaders .. "].")  causes error
    log("UMONIoT","INFO", "File download repstatus [" .. respstatus .. "].")
    --log("UMONIoT","INFO", "File download response_body [" .. response_body .. "].")  causes error
else
    local http = require("socket.http")
    response, resultcode = http.request(url)
    --p(response, resultcode)
end

if resultcode ~= 200 then
    log("UMONIoT","ERROR", "Failed to download file. Error code [" .. resultcode .. "].")
    resultstr = resultstr .. "Failed to download file. Error code [" .. resultcode .. "]."
    return false, nil, nil, resultstr
else
    -- save the content to a file
    if isbinary == true then
        local f = assert(io.open(fulllocalpath, 'wb')) -- open in "binary" mode
        f:write(response)
        f:close()
    else
        local f = assert(io.open(fulllocalpath, 'w'))
        if fname:match("SETUP") then
            local newresponse = updateIPandCredentials(response)
            f:write(newresponse)
            f:close()
        else
            f:write(response)
            f:close()
        end
    end
    log("UMONIoT","INFO", "Successfully downloaded file: " .. fname .. " to gateway.")
    resultstr = resultstr .. "Successfully downloaded file: " .. fname .. " to gateway."
    return true, filename ,fulllocalpath, resultstr
end
```

What is happening is that I can see in wireshark traces that a secure seesion is opened but the connection is immediately reset, stopping the file transfer.

Comment: The comments at the top of your code appear to be missing a `-` to make them valid comments

Comment: Thanks for seeing that, it is just the comment did not copy over, it is there ins my code